# Random Choice Failure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to make it so that it ends after `questnum == 3`. However, what prints after the very first quest marking is this:

```
1:

Stage 3.


x
x
x
x
x
x
x
```

This happens onwards forever. I have no clue what's going on, so please help me out. It is somewhere in the x/y code, because I have commented it out and it works fine. Here is my code:

```
import random

end = False
x = 0
choice = 0
moon = input("x or y? ")
quest = False
currentquest = 0
queststage = 1
questnum = 0
while(True):
    choice = random.randint(1,3)
    if(choice <= 2 and moon.upper() == "X"):
        print("x")
    elif(choice <= 2 and moon.upper() == "Y"):
        print("y")
    if(choice == 3):
        if(quest == False):
            currentquest = random.randint(1,3)
            if(currentquest == 1):
                #Quest 1
                print("1:\n")
                print("Stage 1.\n\n")
                quest = True
            elif(currentquest == 2):
                #Quest 2
                print("2:\n")
                print("Stage 1.\n\n")
                quest = True
            elif(currentquest == 3):
                #Quest 3
                print("3:\n")
                print("Stage 1.\n\n")
                quest = True
        #Continue Quest
        elif(quest == True):
            #Quest 1
            if(currentquest == 1):
                if(queststage == 1):
                    queststage = 2
                    print("1:\n")
                    print("Stage 2.\n\n")
                elif(queststage == 2):
                    queststage = 3
                    print("1:\n")
                    print("Stage 3.\n\n")
                    quest = False
                    questnum += 1
            #Quest 2
            elif(currentquest == 2):
                if(queststage == 1):
                    queststage = 2
                    print("2:\n")
                    print("Stage 2.\n\n")
                elif(queststage == 2):
                    queststage = 1
                    print("2:\n")
                    print("Stage 3.\n\n")
                    quest = False
                    questnum += 1
            #Quest 3
            elif(currentquest == 3):
                if(queststage == 1):
                    queststage = 2
                    print("3:\n")
                    print("Stage 2.\n\n")
                elif(queststage == 2):
                    queststage = 1
                    print("3:\n")
                    print("Stage 3.\n\n")
                    quest = False
                    questnum += 1
    if(questnum == 3):
        print("Complete.")
        break
```

The snippet doesn't work, it was just easier to put it in that way.

Comment: Note that you don't need parenthesis around all of your conditionals, e.g. you can do `while True:` instead of `while(True):`

Comment: Everything will be clearer after you start writing short functions.

Comment: I would recommend reading about the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) of software engineering. You repeat code often in the example. It can be simplified or turned into a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add one line `print(choice,quest,currentquest,queststage,questnum)` right after your while Loop, you will see why.

The result is

```
3 True 3 3 2
1 True 3 3 2
x
3 True 3 3 2
3 True 3 3 2
1 True 3 3 2
x
2 True 3 3 2
x
1 True 3 3 2
x
3 True 3 3 2
1 True 3 3 2
x
1 True 3 3 2
x
3 True 3 3 2
2 True 3 3 2
x
2 True 3 3 2
x
3 True 3 3 2
1 True 3 3 2
x
3 True 3 3 2
3 True 3 3 2
```

Check back to your code, there is no statement for `quest=True`,`currentquest=3`, `queststage=3`, and `questnum=2` in the loop.

Therefore it will run into infinite loop.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't change a number xD

Answer (score 0):

Your break statement is within the if statement and would not break the forever while loop you have executed. What if you change the True for the while to a variable you could toggle in your final if statement.

Comment: It breaks the while loop because it can't break an if statement, so it breaks the furthest while or for loop outside of it. I've tested it, that part works fine-- it actually fixed something else, bringing it to a break statement instead of a toggled variable.